# nested switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have a problem with the code below, I disposed of irrelevant codes.

I have debugged the code and found the problem is that I can't go into **switch (e->u.op.oper)**.

In the function interpExp(), there exists nested switch statement. At there, I can see the output of string, **"good"**. So execution obviously gets there.

But, I can't see **"wow"** output.
Because **"good"** has been printed, the **"wow"** should be printed too, I think.
But I can't see the closely following **"wow"** output, which should occur 
 from the second, nested statement **switch(e->u.op.oper)**.

```
typedef struct A_exp_* A_exp;
typedef enum {A_plus, A_minus, A_times, A_div} A_binop;

struct IntAndTable interpExp(A_exp e, Table_ t) {
    Table_ tempT;
    switch (e->kind) {
        case A_idExp :
            return (struct IntAndTable) {lookup(t, e->u.id), t}; 
        case A_numExp :
            printf("hi\n");
            printf("%d\n", e->u.num);
            return (struct IntAndTable) {e->u.num, t}; 
        case A_opExp :
            printf("good\n");
            switch (e->u.op.oper) {
                printf("wowowowowow\n");
                struct IntAndTable left = interpExp(e->u.op.left, t); 
                struct IntAndTable right = interpExp(e->u.op.right, left.t);
                case A_plus :
                    return (struct IntAndTable) {left.i + right.i, right.t};
                case A_minus :
                    return (struct IntAndTable) {left.i - right.i, right.t};
                case A_times :
                    return (struct IntAndTable) {left.i * right.i, right.t};
                case A_div :
                    return (struct IntAndTable) {left.i / right.i, right.t};
            }
        case A_eseqExp :
            tempT = interpStm(e->u.eseq.stm, t); 
            return interpExp(e->u.eseq.exp, tempT);
    }   
}


struct A_exp_ {
    enum {A_idExp, A_numExp, A_opExp, A_eseqExp} kind;
    union {
        string id; 
        int num;
        struct {
            A_exp left;
            A_binop oper;
            A_exp right;
        } op; 
        struct {
            A_stm stm;
            A_exp exp;
        } eseq;
    } u;
};
```

Comment: Your inner `switch` has no `case` before the desired printf.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala sorry I do not check the title of this question, I modified it just now

Comment: @Yunnosch Doesn't switch statement run codes outside of case?

Comment: @Yunnosch that's not UB. It is just not ever called.

Comment: @sungjuncho no. Also you need to *break* after every case... otherwise they'd fall through. Please read in the [C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4.2)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks for the comment on mine.

Comment: Hello close-voters. This question has a very precise description of what goes wrong and where.. The relevant details are even in bold.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner `switch` has no `case` before the desired `printf`,
which causes the code before the `break` never to be executed.

Credits to Antti Haaapala for the useful link into C-standard in his comment,
in the exmple (or its explanation), it is explicitly stated that code like yours "cannot be reached".